Inconsistency in answers while solving a 2nd order differential equation using operator method
I've been trying to solve this 2nd order differential equation, using the operator method.
$$ y''-3y'+2y= xe^{x} \\
(D^{2}-3D+2)y=xe^{x} \\ $$
My professor solved it using MacLaurin series expansion.
$$y = \frac{xe^{x}}{D(D-1)} \\
y = -e^{x} \frac{1}{D} (1+D+D^{2}+...) \\
 y = -e^{x} (\frac{1}{D}+1+D+D^{2}+...) \\ 
 y=-e^{x}(\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x+1) $$
This, along with the general solution of the corresponding homogenous equation will give the general solution of the equation I asked about.
If I solve it using partial fractions, I'm getting different signs on a few terms.
$$y= (\frac{1}{D-1} - \frac{1}{D}) xe^{x} \\
y= \frac{xe^{x}}{D-1} - \frac{xe^{x}}{D} \\
y=e^{x}\int_{}^{}xdx -(xe^{x}-\int_{}^{}e^{x}dx) \\
y=e^{x} (\frac{x^{2}}{2}-x+1)$$
I can't find any error, why is there a difference? Also, my professor's answer is correct.

$y = \frac{x e^x}{(D-1)(D-2)}$

@Cesareo this can be simplified because $\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{kx} g(x) = \frac{1}{f(D+k)}e^{kx} g(x)$

You need to be more careful in writing down your expressions. $D$ and $x$ do not commute, which is part of the beauty of this method. You can not use commutative writing rules, think more of matrix algebra to get that non-commutative feeling. Thus above comment should be written as $D(e^{kx}g(x))=e^{kx}(D+k)g(x)$ so that $f(D)(e^{kx}g(x))=e^{kx}f(D+k)g(x)$ and also $f(D)^{-1})(e^{kx}g(x))=e^{kx}f(D+k)^{-1}g(x)$.

@LutzLehmann so that's the reason for the difference in signs? My professor did write it like that in his notes but I overlooked this detail, can you elaborate more on why this isn't commutative?

Because $Dx-xD=1$. Or more explicitly, following the product rule, $D(xg(x))=g(x)+xDg(x)$. I did not follow the details, that would have been an answer. The comment was just a hint to check your solution process to find the answer yourself. Sign and constant errors (e.g., transcribing one line to the next) are a common occurrence in (ad-hoc) live presentations of a calculation. So I would not put too much weight into the presented solution vs. your own careful calculations.

Let's write the exponential exchange rule as
$$
e^{kx}(D+m)=(D+m-k)e^{kx},
$$
all factors considered as operators that act first to the right. This means that the full form of above would be
$$
e^{kx}((D+m)g(x))=(D+m-k)(e^{kx}g(x)).
$$
The factorization of the given DE was found to be
$$
(D-1)(D-2)y(x)=xe^x.
$$
Multiplying with $e^{-x}$ (from the left) leads with the rule above to
$$
D(D-1)(e^{-x}y(x))=x.
$$
This can be immediately integrated once,
$$
(D-1)(e^{-x}y(x))=\frac12x^2+c.
$$
The trick of expansion into a geometric series works because the right side is a polynomial, cutting the applied series into a finite expression.
$$
-(e^{-x}y(x))=(1+D+D^2+D^3+...)\left(\frac12x^2+c\right)=\frac12x^2+c+x+1+0+...+0+....
$$

Let's check your approach. Due to the commutativity issue you did not recognize that the exponential was already transported to the front in
$$
y(x)=e^x[D(D-1)]^{-1}x,
$$
so that with the partial fraction you get
$$
y(x)=-e^x[D^{-1}-(D-1)^{-1}]x=-e^x[D^{-1}+1+D+D^2+...]x,
$$
which has lead us back to where we were already.
